# How can i style "select input type" similar way i did to other input fields?

Tags: html, css

I tried to build this form but i want to know how can i style "select" in css similar way i did for other input fields. All i want is to appear 'select for gender' to be above the bottom border line and it translates to -20px on selecting data. Please give a try and let me know how to style the above mentioned in similar way.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #56d8e4 10%,#9f01ea 90%);
}

.container{
  background:#fff;
  width:800px;
  max-width:800px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px;
  box-shadow: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container .text{
  font-size:35px;
  font-weight:600;
  text-align:center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
.container form{
  padding: 30px 0 0 0 0;
}
.container .form-row{
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0; 
}
form .form-row .input-data{
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.textarea{
  height:70px;
}
.input-data select{
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ label,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ label,
.input-data select:focus ~ label
.input-data input:valid ~ label,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ label,
.input-data select:valid ~ label{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  color:#3498db;
  font-size: 14px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input,
.input-data select,
.textarea textarea{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.textarea textarea{
  resize:none;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.input-data label{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.textarea label{
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  background:#fff;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height: 2px;
  width:100%;
  background:#3498db;
}
.input-data .underline:before,
.input-data .underline:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.submit-btn .input-data{
  height: 45px !important;
  width:25% !mportant;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.submit-btn .input-data:hover .inner{
  left:0;
}
.submit-btn .input-data .inner{
  height:100%;
  width:300%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100%;
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.submit-btn .input-data input{
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
@media(max-width:700px){
  .container .text{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .container form{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 0;
  }
  .container form .form-row{
    display:block;
  }
  form .form-row .input-data{
    margin: 35px 0 !important;
  }
  .submit-btn .input-data{
    width:40% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"> Responsive Contact us form</div>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> First name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> last name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Website name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <select id="gender" name="gender">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Gender</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="input-data textarea">
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <textarea cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
          <label> Message</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row submit-btn">
        <div class="input-data">
          <div class="inner"></div>
          <input type="submit" Value="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function myFunction(x) {
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #56d8e4 10%,#9f01ea 90%);
}

.container{
  background:#fff;
  width:800px;
  max-width:800px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px;
  box-shadow: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container .text{
  font-size:35px;
  font-weight:600;
  text-align:center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
.container form{
  padding: 30px 0 0 0 0;
}
.container .form-row{
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0; 
}
form .form-row .input-data{
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.textarea{
  height:70px;
}
.input-data select{
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ label,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ label,
.input-data select:focus ~ label
.input-data input:valid ~ label,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ label,
.input-data select:valid ~ label{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  color:#3498db;
  font-size: 14px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input,
.input-data select,
.textarea textarea{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.textarea textarea{
  resize:none;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.input-data label{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.textarea label{
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  background:#fff;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height: 2px;
  width:100%;
  background:#3498db;
}
.input-data .underline:before,
.input-data .underline:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.submit-btn .input-data{
  height: 45px !important;
  width:25% !mportant;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.submit-btn .input-data:hover .inner{
  left:0;
}
.submit-btn .input-data .inner{
  height:100%;
  width:300%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100%;
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.submit-btn .input-data input{
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
@media(max-width:700px){
  .container .text{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .container form{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 0;
  }
  .container form .form-row{
    display:block;
  }
  form .form-row .input-data{
    margin: 35px 0 !important;
  }
  .submit-btn .input-data{
    width:40% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"> Responsive Contact us form</div>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> First name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> last name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Website name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <select id="gender" name="gender">
                        <option disabled selected value>Gender</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label style="display:none;" onfocus="myfunction()"> Gender</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="input-data textarea">
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <textarea cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
          <label> Message</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row submit-btn">
        <div class="input-data">
          <div class="inner"></div>
          <input type="submit" Value="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

Expand sn
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #56d8e4 10%,#9f01ea 90%);
}

.container{
  background:#fff;
  width:800px;
  max-width:800px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px;
  box-shadow: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container .text{
  font-size:35px;
  font-weight:600;
  text-align:center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
.container form{
  padding: 30px 0 0 0 0;
}
.container .form-row{
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0; 
}
form .form-row .input-data{
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.textarea{
  height:70px;
}
.input-data select{
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ label,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ label,
.input-data select:focus ~ label
.input-data input:valid ~ label,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ label,
.input-data select:valid ~ label{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  color:#3498db;
  font-size: 14px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.input-data input,
.input-data select,
.textarea textarea{
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.textarea textarea{
  resize:none;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.input-data label{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.textarea label{
  width:100%;
  bottom:30px;
  background:#fff;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height: 2px;
  width:100%;
  background:#3498db;
}
.input-data .underline:before,
.input-data .underline:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:focus ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after,
.input-data select:valid ~ .underline:before, .underline:after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.submit-btn .input-data{
  height: 45px !important;
  width:25% !mportant;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.submit-btn .input-data:hover .inner{
  left:0;
}
.submit-btn .input-data .inner{
  height:100%;
  width:300%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100%;
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #56d8e4,#9f01ea );
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.submit-btn .input-data input{
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
@media(max-width:700px){
  .container .text{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .container form{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 0;
  }
  .container form .form-row{
    display:block;
  }
  form .form-row .input-data{
    margin: 35px 0 !important;
  }
  .submit-btn .input-data{
    width:40% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"> Responsive Contact us form</div>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> First name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> last name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label> Website name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <select id="gender" name="gender">
         <option disabled selected value>Gender</option>
         <option value="male">Male</option>
         <option value="female">Female</option>
         <option value="others">Others</option>
       </select>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label style="display:none;"> Gender</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="input-data textarea">
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <textarea cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
          <label> Message</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row submit-btn">
        <div class="input-data">
          <div class="inner"></div>
          <input type="submit" Value="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).